# about keeping one home pepper plant from drying out

Tags: dryness, protection

I have a pepper plant that I watered every day and behind the window received a soft light basement and it is now drying I wanted to see what he did for it and this problem of water or light or soil, also you can see its situation for now:

[image]

Thank